# Return statement is returning null instead of the given value

Tags: android

I am writing an Android Application and encountered a very strange bug I cannot wrap my head around. In the code below the variable "result" is filled with values depending on different conditions. Then it should be returned. In the debugger one can see that the value for result is set correctly. However when reaching the return statement (at this point result has the correctly value according to the debugger) the method does return null instead of the value in result. I have also tried cleaning the project and compiling the code on another machine with the same results. I can't possibly imagine what goes wrong here, however it seems to me that something goes wrong during the compiling process.

I am using a 64-bit jdk1.7.0_79 on a Windows 10 machine and running the code on a Nexus 7 (2012) Emulator with Android Studio Version 1.3.1

Thanks very much for your help in advance.

```
 private static WikiItemContainer getMappingForIntermediateThrowEvent(IntermediateThrowEvent intermediateThrowEvent, List<WikiItemContainer> eventContainers) {
    WikiItemContainer result = null;
    List<EventDefinition> eventDefinitions = intermediateThrowEvent.getEventDefinitions();
    if (eventDefinitions.isEmpty()) {
        result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(0).getItems().get(1));
    } else if (eventDefinitions.size() > 1) {
        result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(10).getItems().get(6));
    } else {
        EventDefinition definition = eventDefinitions.get(0);
        if (definition instanceof MessageEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(1).getItems().get(6));
        } else if (definition instanceof EscalationEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(3).getItems().get(4));
        } else if (definition instanceof LinkEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(5).getItems().get(1));
        } else if (definition instanceof CompensateEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(8).getItems().get(2));
        } else if (definition instanceof SignalEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(9).getItems().get(6));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific class of `definition` when the null is returned? It is probably `EventDefinition`, which is not handled in your if statements

Comment: Did you try logging whether result is null just before the return statement?

Comment: Yeah it is an object of type WikiItemContainer as one would expect and as the debugger shows.

Comment: Try  `Object definition ...` instead of `EventDefinition definition`

Comment: The unit test I am using to run the code is inputting an empty list, so that definition isn't even initialized, I don't think the definition object is the core of the problem. @AlLelopath

Comment: If this list is empty, then `definition` will be null, and as adelphus points out, so will be `result`

Answer (score 1):

There is one condition where `result` is null:

```
 private static WikiItemContainer getMappingForIntermediateThrowEvent(IntermediateThrowEvent intermediateThrowEvent, List<WikiItemContainer> eventContainers) {
    WikiItemContainer result = null;
    List<EventDefinition> eventDefinitions = intermediateThrowEvent.getEventDefinitions();
    if (eventDefinitions.isEmpty()) {
        result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(0).getItems().get(1));
    } else if (eventDefinitions.size() > 1) {
        result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(10).getItems().get(6));
    } else {
        EventDefinition definition = eventDefinitions.get(0);
        if (definition instanceof MessageEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(1).getItems().get(6));
        } else if (definition instanceof EscalationEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(3).getItems().get(4));
        } else if (definition instanceof LinkEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(5).getItems().get(1));
        } else if (definition instanceof CompensateEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(8).getItems().get(2));
        } else if (definition instanceof SignalEventDefinition) {
            result = new WikiItemContainer(eventContainers.get(9).getItems().get(6));
        }


       // What value will result have here if none of the if statements above are entered?

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but in my case result has the correct value just before the return statement, return however returns null anyway. That's what leaves me puzzled.

Comment: That is not possible. In all cases like these, the developer has made a mistake - either looking at the wrong variable, wrong thread or something else. The code never lies!

Comment: I thought the same before, however there could be the small chance that there is some really strange bug in the compiler/emulator as I cannot seem to make sense about why the return is ignoring the real value at runtime (which looks like being set according to logging output/debugger).

Comment: Anyway replace all "result ="   with "return"

Comment: That's what I tried before with a "return null;" in the last line of the method. It resulted in the debugger jumping to the "return null;" line after executing the appropriate return statement (which should also not be possible). That's why I thought that somewhere in the binary file he saved the bytecode equivalent of return null in that line and I tried cleaning the project (without success).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log definition?
Try

```
Log.v("xxxx","definition:."+definition.getClass().Name());
```

And log the size of eventDefinition list

```
Log.v("xxxx","event definition size: "+eventDefinition.size());
```

Comment: The bug is occuring in a unit test where eventDefinitions is intentionally empty, therefore definition is never even initialized and the list is empty as expected.